# Run a background script inside a docker

Tags: shell, docker, background

I want to keep running 2 shell scripts inside my container. These scripts shall start as I start the container.

```
FROM centos:8

# Update the image with the latest packages (recommended)
RUN yum update -y && yum install libnsl net-tools -y && yum clean all; 

RUN mkdir -p /home/abc
ENV HOME /home/abc
WORKDIR ${HOME}

COPY *.gz /home/abc/
COPY start.sh /home/abc

RUN ls *.gz | xargs -i tar xf {} && rm *.gz

RUN bash -c "sh /home/abc/start.sh & sleep 5 && tail -f /dev/null"

EXPOSE 1234
EXPOSE 5678
```

Contents of `start.sh` are

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/abc/abc1/
./process1.sh &

cd /home/abc/abc2/
./process2.sh &
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: I want to ensure that the container will be in running state till I stop. Also if possible I would like to enter in the container to perform operations if required.

Comment: What's wrong with your solution? Please use the [Edit] button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us suppose the contents of `process1.sh` and `process2.sh` are fine, so your `Dockerfile` should look like this:

```
FROM centos:8

# Update the image with the latest packages (recommended)
RUN yum update -y && yum install libnsl net-tools -y && yum clean all; 

RUN mkdir -p /home/abc
ENV HOME /home/abc
WORKDIR ${HOME}

COPY *.gz /home/abc/
COPY start.sh /home/abc
RUN chmod +x /home/abc/start.sh

RUN ls *.gz | xargs -i tar xf {} && rm *.gz

EXPOSE 1234
EXPOSE 5678
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/abc/start.sh"]
```

I removed `RUN bash -c "sh /home/abc/start.sh & sleep 5 && tail -f /dev/null"` because I believe it's not needed. Also as your `start.sh` starts with shebang `#!/bin/bash`, so you'd better to run with `bash`, not `sh` as you may encounter issues as `bash` and `dash` has some differences.

The other thing I think you can do is edit your `start.sh` contents if these two files do not have permission to execute:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/abc/abc1/ && chmod +x process1.sh
./process1.sh &

cd /home/abc/abc2/ && chmod +x process2.sh
./process2.sh &
```

Also if you `.gz` files do not create `abc1` and `abc2` directories inside the `/home/abc`, then you should add `RUN mkdir -p /home/abc/abc1` and `RUN mkdir -p /home/abc/abc2` to your `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest your Dockerfile takes care of setting permissions on that script and runs it like so:

```
...
COPY start.sh /home/abc
RUN chmod -v +x /home/abc/start.sh
CMD ["/home/abc/start.sh"]
```

Then in your start.sh, use whatever your preferred approach is to create an endless loop that calls your other scripts.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.
set -e

for (( ; ; ))
do
    # Your shell scripts should go in here.  I've got them commented
    # and am just running a few commands instead
    #/home/abc/abc1/process1.sh &
    #/home/abc/abc2/process2.sh &
    ls /
    cat /etc/passwd

    # Sleep for 1 seconds
    sleep 1
done
```